# Defining a mapping from a set to a set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

How to define a map that takes a finite binary string of length $L$ to a real number in $[a,b]$
where length $L$ is the number of bits constituting the string

$x=0101$ is a binary string of length $L=4$

I am looking for something simple ...

thanks

Comment: What properties you would like your map to have?

Comment: Better be bijective

Comment: There is no bijective map from the set of all binary strings of finite length to $[a,b]$.  The former is a countable set and the latter is not!

Comment: Hahah yes, I have noticed, then there are no conditions. Just a map

Comment: Better have some conditions, or you'll have to settle for the map that takes every binary string to $a$. Can't get much simpler than that!

Comment: Well, without any conditions the constant map $f\equiv a$ would be an example.  But I'm sure you are thinking of something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A binary string $S$ of length at most $L$, if interpreted as a binary number, satisfies $0\leq S \leq 2^L-1$.  So you can just map the interval $[0, 2^L-1]$ linearly into $[a,b]$.  $$S\mapsto a+(b-a)\frac S{2^L-1}$$